# try catch is not working on isDisplayed() in selenium and throwing s

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Element is not present on the page!

here is the code:

```
try {
        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text()='Duplicate Saved Filter'])")).isDisplayed()) {
   
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text()=' Yes '])")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
    }} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        logger.info("element not found");
        }
```

Comment: There are conditions in which element is present and but not visible and in that case if i use the .size>0 method i would also throw error so that is why i'm using isDisplayed.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB what i'm trying to do is that if element is found it is supposed to run the condition. if it is not found, it should catch the exception and continue with code rather than throwing an error.

Comment: How does `isDisplayed()` helps instead of the regular `findElement()` if the Element is not present on the page?

Comment: hmmm i can't understand what you are saying. can you please explain? thanks

Comment: in simple words, why using `isDisplayed()` when you can verify the presence/displayedness through `findElement()`

Comment: because element is sometimes present on page but not visible. @DebanjanB

Answer (score 1):

What you want:

- click on Yes if element is present and visible
- otherwise log something, without error throwing

The trick here is to use findElement**S** (notice the **S**). This gives a list of found elements, if 0 than there is no element (prevents the error throwing).
If there is an element, check if it is displayed.
From your comment I guess you tried to use findElement**S** but forgot to add the .size() > 0 check.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[text()='Duplicate Saved Filter'])"));
if(elements.size() == 0) {
    logger.info("element not found");
} else if(!elements[0].Displayed())) {
    logger.info("element not visisble");
} else {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text()=' Yes '])")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: i think your answer is close to what i did already. copy paste it in notepad and let me know what do you think about this.